# Randomly move a certain number of items in a Python list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting

So I've been doing some sorting algorithms and I want to run a test function that generates lists of different varieties to run my sorting algorithms on.

One such list would be an already sorted list, where n number of the items in the list have been shuffled around randomly (but not all of them, the list should still be sorted other than the n items)

```
testlist = random.sample(range(0,10),10)
testlist.sort()
```

This gives me a sorted list of unique items of size 10, but then I'm unsure how to go about moving **n** of these 10 items around the list to a random location, just to mix the sorting up

Comment: Why is it important to move **n** of them? It seems like you could just generate the random list, pass it to your code, and then call `testlist.sort()` to produce the "correct" value afterwards.

Comment: Do you have to move them, or would it be enough to regenerate them -- likely getting a value that is out of order?

Comment: @AustinHastings I already intend on doing that, but I'm basically comparing the runtimes for a lot of common sorting algorithms on various lists such as sorted lists, reverse sorted lists, randomly sorted, each of which I will generate of various sizes, and a sorted list with some elements moved is something I'd like to compare against a completely sorted list in regards to runtime

Comment: Can you define "move" more clearly? If the sorted list is [0, 1, 2, 3] and I generate [1, 2, 3, 0] from it, how many items have moved? The answer could be 4 (move = change index) or 1 (the smallest number of items that need to be pulled out and reinserted to get a sorted list). I'd *guess* it's the latter (which is more tricky to implement) but other answers seem to assume it's the former.

Comment: @gill what I mean by "move" is if we have the sorted list [0,1,2,3,4] and then I want to move n = 2 items chosen randomly, a possible new list would be [4,1,2,3,0]

Comment: Well, this doesn't help. With [0,1,2,3,4] -> [4,1,2,3,0], two items have changed indices and the smallest number of items we need to "pull out and re-insert" is also two. So it does nothing to resolve the ambiguity. Please clarify with respect to [0,1,2,3] -> [1,2,3,0]. How many items have moved there?

Comment: Or clarify whether, according to your definition, n can be *1*. If it can, you are not having index-swapping in mind (it's impossible to change the index of just one item), and AFAIK none of the answers gives you what want.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to shuffle some items in the list:

```
import random
import numpy as np

# Make a sorted list of integers.
x = np.array(range(100))

# Choose 10 indices at random.
r = random.sample(range(len(x)), 10)

# Copy this list and shuffle.
s = r.copy()
random.shuffle(s)

# Replace the indices with the shuffled ones.
x[r] = x[s]
```

Note this might leave some indices unchanged.

Comment: This is actually a really interesting way of implementing it

Answer (score 3):

Here's a controlled implementation.
Pick four indices at random to get switched.  Shuffle those values, and put them back into the four designated spots.  Note that it does not guarantee that the new values will all be different.

```
import random
import copy

testlist = random.sample(range(0, 20), 10)
testlist.sort()
print testlist

n = 4
move_set = set()
while len(move_set) < n:
    move_set.add(random.randrange(0, 10))

print move_set
move_list = list(move_set)

# Replace n elements
test1 = copy.copy(testlist)
migrant = [test1[_] for _ in move_set]
random.shuffle(migrant)
print migrant
test_case = []
for i in range(n):
    test1[move_list[i]] = migrant[i]
print test1
```

Output:

```
[0, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 12, 16, 17]
set([9, 3, 4, 5])
[5, 17, 8, 7]
[0, 3, 4, 17, 8, 7, 9, 12, 16, 5]
```

In this run, it's only coincidence that all four indices were also values in the list.  Elements 9, 3, 4, and 5 have values 17, 5, 7, and 8, respectively.  The shuffle puts each of the four into new locations.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work.  Basically, just pick two indexes at random and switch them, and not switching the same index more than once.  If run on a sorted array, it does guarantee that exactly `n` elements are unsorted.  Only works on even number replacements though.

```
array = list(range(10))

def shuffle_n(array, n):
    assert n <= len(array) and n % 2 == 0
    indexes = set(range(len(array)))
    for i in range(n // 2):
        a, b = random.sample(indexes, 2)
        indexes.remove(a)
        indexes.remove(b)
        array[a], array[b] = array[b], array[a]
```